# R raster timeseries: what's the most efficient read and write?

Tags: r, performance, time-series, r-raster

I have the following problem/question:

I've written an R functions which is smoothing values from a time series. The time series is defined by a big number of single global raster files, hence each single pixel a series with `n` timesteps (generally more than 500). Even though I've plenty of RAM, I have to rely on blockwise processing because loading the entire dataset is just too much. So far so good.

I've written (IMHO) a fairly decent code, which leverages parallel processing when possible. I have a processing machine which should be more than well equipped to handle this amount of data and computation. This leads me to believe that most of the time will be spent by reading lots of values from the disk and then, after smoothing, writing lots of values to the disk.

So I've tried running the code with the files being on either a normal HDD or a normal SSD.
Against my expectations, it didn't really matter much.
Then I tried running a test function which reads a file, gets the values and writes them back to disk with the raster being on either the HDD, the SSD or a blazing fast SSD. Again, no significant difference.

I've already done a fair share of profiling to find bottlenecks, as well as a good amount of time googling for efficient solutions. There's bits of info here and there, but I decided to post this question here to get a definitive answer and maybe some pointers for me and others how to efficient manage things.

So without further ado (and for people who skipped the above), here's my question:

In a setting as described above (high data volume, blockwise processing, reading and writing from/to disk), **what's the most efficient (and/or fastest) way to do computation on a long raster time series which involves reading and writing values from/to disk?** (especially regarding the read write aspect)

Assuming I have a fast SSD, how can I leverage the speed? Is it done automatically? 
What are the influencing factors (filesize, filetype, caching)  and the most efficient setting of these factors?

I know that in terms of raster, R works the fastest with `.grd`, but I would like to avoid this format for flexibility, compatibility and diskspace reasons.

Maybe I'm also having a misconception of how the `raster` package interacts with the files on disk. In that case, should I use different functions than `getValues` and `writeValues` ?

-- Some system info and example code: --

```
Os: Win7 x64
CPU: Xenon E5-1650 @ 3.5 GHz
RAM: 128 GB 
R-version: 3.2
Raster file format: .rst
```

Read/write benchmark function:

```
benchfun <- function(x){
  # x ... raster file

  xr <- raster(x)
  x2 <- raster(xr)

  xval <- getValues(xr)

  x2 <- setValues(x2,xval)

  writeRaster(x2,'testras.tif',overwrite=TRUE)

}
```

If needed I can also provide a little example code for the time series processing, but for now I don't think it's needed.

Appreciate all tips!

Thanks,

Val

Comment: Is your time series saved as a "single file" or do you access it through a `rasterStack` ? In the first case, one possible way to speed-up things could be indeed to play with format and interleave (I write possible because I didn't test it). Usually, processing on time series is faster on files saved in BIP (Band interleaved by pixel) format (don't know which interleave is used by default in a multiband geoTIFF, though), so saving in a BIP format (and maybe reading through `readGDAL`), could help. Also, any kind of compression on the TIFF would slow down things. HTH.

Comment: As for now the time series consists of single raster files (.rst) on disk and I'm reading the values blockwise and in parallel. I haven't tried BIP, but I'm considering other file formats which could contain the entire TS in a single file (such as HDF5).

Comment: I think that using a single multi band file could speed up things. Consider that BIP is not a format, but just an interleave type. In some formats You can save with the same format but different interleaves. BIP is considered the fastest for analyses on the spectral/time axis. A good format for you could be ENVI binary, which is supported by gdal.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll give it a try!

Comment: You're welcome. If you do some benchmarking, I'd be interested to see the results !

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, also trying to speed up time series smoothing function. Would the process be optimised by working with a virtual stack (created with the gdaUtils package)?